# Reordering rows and columns in R

Tags: r

I know this has been answered before, but, 
given a correlation matrix which looks like this:

```
V  A    B    C     D 
A  1    0.3  0.1   0.4
B  0.2  1    0.4   0.3
C  0.1  0    1     0.9
D  0.3  0.3  0.1   1
```

which can be loaded in R as follows:

```
corr.matrix <- read.table("path/to/file", sep = '\t', header = T)
rownames(corr.matrix) <- corr.matrix$V
corr.matrix <- corr.matrix[, 2:ncol(corr.matrix)]
```

Based on 2 other files that dictate which of the rows and columns to be plotted (Because some are of no interest to me), I want to rearrange the rows and columns in to how the 2 separate files dictate.

For example:

```
cols_order.txt                      
C
D
E
B
A
...

rows.txt
D
E
Z
B
T
A
...
```

I read those other 2 files like this:

```
rows.order <- ("rows_order.txt", sep = '\n', header=F)
colnames(rows.order) <- "Variant"

cols.order <- ("cols_order.txt", sep = '\n', header=F)
colnames(cols.order) <- "Variant"
```

And after this step I do this:

```
corr.matrix <- corr.matrix[rows.order$Variant, cols.order$Variant]
```

The values that I don't want to be plotted are successfully removed, but the order gets scrambled. How can I fix this?

The `.order` datasets are read correctly (I checked 3 times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a potential solution to your question. I tried to re-create a small-sized data.frame based on your question. The key here is the `match` function as well as some basic subsetting/filtering techniques in R:

```
## Re-create your example:
V <- data.frame(
  A = c(1 ,  0.3, 0.1 , 0.4),
  B = c(0.2, 1 ,  0.4 , 0.3),
  C = c(0.1, 0 ,  1  ,  0.9),
  D = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.1 , 1)
) #matrix() also ok
rownames(V) <- LETTERS[1:4]

## Reorder using `match` function
## Needs to be in data.frame form
## So use as.data.frame() if needed

## Here, I don't have the text file
## So if you want to load in txt files specifying rows columns
## Use `read.csv` or `read.table to load
## And then store the relevant info into a vector as you did

col_order <- c("C","D","E","B","A")
col_order_filtered <- col_order[which(col_order %in% colnames(V))]
rows <- c("D","E","Z","B","T","A")
## Filter rows IDs, since not all are present in your data
row_filtered <- rows[rows %in% rownames(V)]

V1 <- V[match(rownames(V), row_filtered), match(colnames(V), col_order_filtered)]
V1 <- V1[-which(rownames(V1)=="NA"), ]
V1

##     D   C   A   B
## C 0.1 1.0 0.1 0.4
## B 0.3 0.0 0.3 1.0
## A 0.3 0.1 1.0 0.2
```

Alternatively, if you are comfortable with `dplyr` package and the syntax, you can use it and often it is handy:

```
## Continued from previous code
library(dplyr)
V2 <- V %>%
  select(C, D, B, A, everything()) %>%
  slice(match(rownames(V), row_filtered))
rownames(V2) <- row_filtered
V2
##     C   D   B   A
## D 1.0 0.1 0.4 0.1
## B 0.0 0.3 1.0 0.3
## A 0.1 0.3 0.2 1.0
```

Hope that helps.